# Redirect www.mysite.com/someurl/xyz/products to Redirect www.mysite.com/someurl/abc/products

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

How to Redirect www.mysite.com/someurl/xyz/products to Redirect www.mysite.com/someurl/abc/products.

Please note /xyz/ to /abc/

Thank

Comment: is "someurl" always going to be the same or dynamic?

Answer (score 1):

If all is static, you just have to do it that way : (and maybe personalise the R code with R=301 or R=302...)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^someurl/xyz/products$ /someurl/abc/products [R,L]
```